# Applied Coupon title "Discount" is not translating on cart & checkout Magento2

Tags: magento2

Applied Coupon code title `Discount`is not `translating` in Magento2,
even if we applied the `Extra Fee`, that is not translating, rather then this everything is translating properly.

for more please see my screen shot.  [image]

Comment: give me  translated text which you want to add

Comment: I want to translate it to  Rabatt

Comment: Have you add translated text in CSV file?

Comment: yes i know it please give me your text how to translate text

Comment: I used all these three options and all together also
Discount Rabatt
Discount (%1) Rabatt (%1)
Discount (%s) Rabatt (%s)

Comment: First Time Its load the Rabatt but within second its again updated to Discount

Answer (score 2):

Add translated text  in your theme `de_DE.csv` file. given below location.

> app/design/frontend/ThemeFolder/ThemeName/i18n/de_DE.csv

Add below text.

```
discount, Rabatt
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: i am using these , Discount Rabatt
Discount (%1) Rabatt (%1)
Discount (%s) Rabatt (%s)

Comment: Your Solution is not working for Discount.
First Time Its load the Rabatt but within second its again updated to Discount.